# Creating an alias for an instantiated template

Tags: c++, templates

I originally had a number of signal processing filter classes that were identical apart from a few constants defining the filter characteristic, so I decided to change these to a template class for maintainability and extensibility.  There are performance and memory management reasons for preferring a template over constructor arguments in this case; it is for an embedded system.

Consequently I have a template class of the form:

```
template <int SIZE, int SCALE_MULTIPLIER, int SCALE_SHIFT>
class cBoxcarFilter
{
public:
    // Allow access to SIZE at runtime.
    static const int FILTER_SIZE = SIZE ;
    ...
}
```

Which I explicitly instantiate thus, for example:

```
template class cBoxcarFilter<8, 1, 3>
```

The problem is when I need to access the FILTER_SIZE member it requires:

```
cBoxcarFilter<8, 1, 3>::FILTER_SIZE
```

which rather makes access to FILTER_SIZE redundant since it must be repeated in the arguments.  My solution to this problem is this:

```
// Create an alias for filter
#define cSpecialistBoxcarFilter cBoxcarFilter<8, 1, 3>
template class cSpecialistBoxcarFilter ;
```

then I can access FILTER_SIZE thus:

```
cSpecialistBoxcarFilter::FILTER_SIZE
```

this also has the advantage of meaningful unique names for each filter instance as in the original non-templated versions, but it seems somewhat smelly to me using a macro that looks like a class since it has different scope semantics.

Is there a better way of creating alias class names for a template instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `typedef`!

```
typedef cBoxcarFilter<8, 1, 3> cSpecialistBoxcarFilter;
```

Comment: That was obvious now you say it! ;)  Must be asleep. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the explicit template instantiation must still use the full form.  `template class cBoxcarFilter<8, 1, 3>;`.  But everywhere else, you can use this typedef as a name for the specialized class type.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask concrete instances (objects) of your class for their filter size:

```
template <int X> class A
{
  public:
  int y;
  static const int size = X;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  A<3> a;
  printf("size is %i\n", a.size);
}
```

result

```
size is 3
```

Comment: That should be `.`, not `::`.  Oh, and that will work for statics, but not e.g. typedefs.

Comment: @DanDan: No, I mean for accessing inner typedefs defined within the template.  e.g. if the class template defined `typedef int[X] Y;`, you couldn't do either `a.Y` or `a::Y`.